# c# generic if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have 4 lists. some of them filled with data and some of them empty.
i want to make a if statement which will consider only the lists which has elements,
if a list empty, i dont want to see it in if condition.

```
            List<int> list1 = new List<int> {1,2,3 };
            List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
            List<string> list3 = new List<string> { "cc", "cc", "cc" };
            List<string> list4 = new List<string> { "dd", "dd", "dd" };
             

            if (list1.Contains(1) && list2.Contains("bb") && list3.Contains("cc") && list4.Contains("dd"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("condition okey");
            }
```

as you see in the code example, the list2 is empty, and i dont want to include it inside the if statement.
i fill these lists from Database. and i dont know, which one will be empty.

how can i write a generic if statement.
thank you.

Comment: "and i dont know, which one will be empty." Well, then you don't know which one not to include. Why are you trying to exclude these conditions anyway? What's wrong with putting all of them in?

Comment: @Sweeper   the data comes from db and it s an erp app. if a list filled with data, it means, it has requirements.so i m trying to do it.

Comment: Is list 2 "ok" because it is empty? If so, you just need additional checks for each list.

Comment: Okay, now I see. You should [edit] your question to explain more clearly. Basically an empty list means "the list contains everything" right? How about adding an `|| listN.IsEmpty` to each condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ((!list1.Any() || list1.Contains(1))
  && (!list2.Any() || list2.Contains("bb"))
  && (!list3.Any() || list3.Contains("cc"))
  && (!list4.Any() || list4.Contains("dd")))
{
  MessageBox.Show("condition okey");
}
```

Here is a solution using a generic extension method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    List<int> list1 = new List<int> {1,2,3 };
    List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
    List<string> list3 = new List<string> { "cc", "cc", "cc" };
    List<string> list4 = new List<string> { "dd", "dd", "dd" };

    if (list1.IsEmptyOrContains(1) 
      && list2.IsEmptyOrContains("bb") 
      && list3.IsEmptyOrContains("cc") 
      && list4.IsEmptyOrContains("dd"))
    {
      Console.WriteLine("condition okey");
    }
  }
}

public static class ListExtensions
{
  public static bool IsEmptyOrContains<T>(this List<T> l, T c)
  {
    return !l.Any() || l.Contains(c);
  }
}
```

Comment: yes. it worked. my mistake was trying with count method. thank u sir.

Comment: You could create an extension method to encapsulate the not any check and the contains, which would make this a bit more readable, but I would only recommend that if it was something you were going to do a lot.

Comment: @FkBey Updated answer with the extension method for your reference.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use [?: operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) to determine whether a list contains elements. If not, return true directly.

```
if ((list1.Count != 0 ? list1.Contains(1) : true )
    && (list2.Count != 0 ? list2.Contains("bb") : true)
    && (list3.Count != 0 ? list3.Contains("cc") : true)
    && (list4.Count != 0 ? list4.Contains("dd") : true))
{
    MessageBox.Show("condition okey");
}
```

Comment: i thought about it , but if the    List<string> list2 = new List<string> { "xx", "xx", "xx" };
again the condition is true.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, need to add the `()`.

Comment: @FkBey This solution should work, as if list2 contains xx's, then list2.Count would !=0 and then it would consider list2.Contains("bb") which would be false.  I prefer my answer only because it uses Any instead of Count.  With a list, the difference is minimal, but with other enumerables, .Any would be faster because it only has to check to see if there is 1 or more, where count may require iterating the entire enumerable to get the count.  List fortunately optimizes count, and it already knows it, so the difference here is trivial.

Comment: @Kyle Wang  no problems. it s solved. thank you for your time.

Comment: @RobertMcKee Yes, `!list.Any()` is a better choice to determine whether the list contains elements.

Comment: @RobertMcKee yes sir. before editing the answer, the if statement was withoug ().
i tried it and it was false. after that u sent the answer, it worked. everything happend so fast. really thank u for mr Kyle Wang and mr Robert McKee. and i m totally aware of the speed of the Any().